# Where to get information about moving to another country?

Tags: discussion

I'm currently planning to move to Ireland one day. I currently live in Austria and visit a higher school.

I want to go to university in Austria, but right after graduation with my master's degree I want to move to Ireland asap.

In order to find the perfect university or plan my future best, I need some information about moving to other countries, especially Ireland.

These are questions like:

- How much money should one save before moving?
- Where can you get contact to Irish people to already have someone to talk to?
- How are job perspectives in the other country?
- How should one apply to jobs or apartments?

Which websites or consulting services (in Austria) exist`?

Answer (score 3):

Really not the right place to post (here on meta).  You should be posting travel questions on [travel.stackexchange.com](https://travel.stackexchange.com/), and information on moving/expats on [expatriates.stackexchange.com](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).  But make sure you read the help on each site, and don't ask more than one question per post - it makes it easier for the knowledge experts to find your questions :)